# Visual Studio Deploying Queue Trigger Azure Function

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-storage, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

I am currently running through the tutorial written [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs) for creating and deploying a queue triggered azure function.

In the "Create a function" section on step 2, it isn't clear to me what we are supposed to put for the "Connection" string. I am assuming it is the storage account name that you want the function to use.

The other issue I am having is when I have set up and tested the Azure Function on my local system, I go to deploy it to Azure and I am not presented with an option to select a current storage account to use.

[image]

I believe this is causing a new storage account to be created when I publish the function to azure. This is very frustrating because that means I have to use a storage account with an ugly GUID and also have to create a new storage queue. Am I missing a step somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what we are supposed to put for the "Connection" string.

When you create a new project using the Azure Functions template, you get an empty C# project that contains the following files: **host.json** and **local.settings.json**, and you can specify connection strings to other Azure services (such as Azure storage) in local.settings.json file. And then you can set value of **Connection option** with connection string name when you create a function.

***local.settings.json***

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={your_account_name};AccountKey={your_account_key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={your_account_name};AccountKey={your_account_key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  }
}
```

***Create a function and set value of Connection option with `AzureWebJobsStorage`***

[image]

> I am not presented with an option to select a current storage account to use.

I’m using Visual studio 2017 Version 15.3.0 preview 7.1 and Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools Version 15.0.30923.0, It provides the option to choose **Storage account**. If possible, please upgrade your Visual Studio and update your Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools.

[image]